# IE7 a tag float left bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

HTML

```
 <a href="#">M1</a>
 <a href="#">M2</a>
 <a href="#">M3</a>
 <a href="#" class="front">FirstONE</a>
```

CSS

```
a.front{float:left;}
```

ONLINE SAMPLE: http://jsbin.com/anirot/2

the other browsers are fine just **IE7**, looks `front` class cannot display at the front. Is there any tricks could get it fixed? I've try display inline or block, doesnt help at all. even `*display:inline, zoom:1`

Thanks

Comment: Just as note, IE7 is less than 2% marketshare and going down; not often that you've got time playing in your favor: http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0

Comment: @frenchie Thanks :-) good resource. Would be happy to know if someone has a solution

Comment: Ouch IE7... I feel your pain!

Answer (score 0):

Put `front` link in HTML before other three ones. If you need exact HTML structure you've shown, move the element to corresponding position in HTML via JavaScript for IE7 only.